# jodit add button to insert html in editor

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-wysiwyg, jodit

There has been a few posts on a similar subject.  However none of the solutions are working in my case.

I have managed to add a new button with the code below but when I click on it nothing happens.

```
<script>
var editor = new Jodit('#editor', {
    buttons: [
        'bold',
        {
            iconURL: './icons/icon.png',
            exec: function (editor) {
                return editor.create.fromHTML('text to insert');
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Next step will be to add a new button with a dropdown of several insert options, each of these to insert a different html text in the editor.

Anybody has done that?

Comment: I have been asking this simple question 9 days ago and no reply... I also email the developer of Jodit... no reply neither.  Is there nobody who can help... please?

Answer (score 0):

Just look jodit [documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/)

Corrections of your code:

```
var editor = new Jodit('#editor', {
    buttons: [
        {   
            name: 'bold',
            tooltip: 'Bold'
            iconURL: './icons/icon.png',
            exec: function (editor) {
                editor.selection.insertHTML('text to insert');
            }
        }
    ]
 });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I copy your code instead of mine but then then the editor does not display at all, only the textarea field.  Is there a live example somewhere?

Comment: Thank you Antonio.  I know the playground but it does not allow to create a custom button to add html text... However, I found the mistake...     buttons: 'bold', { ... works.
So now, I need help to creqate a dropdown list with a few items, each of them to insert different html text... do you know how to do that?